# How can I set up VS Code Server with GitHub Enterprise instead of standard GitHub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, vscode-remote, vscode-server

I'm trying to use VS Code server to create a remote development environment through AWS. The problem is that my corporation has pretty tight security requirements, and would prefer that the initial setup of VS Code server use GitHub Enterprise instead of the standard GitHub.

Specifically, I'm referring to this step:
[VS Code Server is asking about github.com, not GitHub Enterprise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzkD2.png)

I've tried logging into VS Code with GHE, but no dice. Maybe I could log into GHE on AWS? Not sure. Any advice would be appreciated!